# Scrolling content with negative margins

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I have generated XAML file from Windows Forms, and with the process calculated right and bottom margins because they do not exist in Forms. I have this output:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="129" Height="18" Margin="36,46,278,686" />
    ...
    <TextBox Width="54" Height="18" Margin="345,705,83,31" />
    <TextBox Width="54" Height="18" Margin="345,728,83,8" />
    <TextBox Width="54" Height="18" Margin="345,770,83,-34" /> 
    ...
</Grid>
```

The problem is that Content of Grid is too large, even for the designer, so scroll bar is generated in win forms. However, this is not case in WPF, so I try adding ScrollViewer around it. But it only scrolls down to content with positive bottom margin. Controls with negative margins are not shown anywhere.

Any idea how to solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grid` is the wrong thing for this task. If you're going to do the positioning yourself, you should use a [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) and then use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to position it. You don't need the `Bottom` or `Right` values since you seem to know the `Width` and `Height`.

I believe you should be able to use the `ScrollViewer` around the `Canvas` object too.

Comment: I have tried it now, but my elements are still not visible. The problem is that the Canvas has around 500 height and element has Canvas.Top around 1000. If I make it smaller my controls will be too dense packed.

Comment: Well if you're setting your `Canvas.Top` values to be 1000, you're going to be off the screen of just about any application (thinking normal full screen apps will be less than 1280x1024 in size). So if you have to position your elements that far away from the the origin for whatever reason, then you need to add a `ScrollViewer` around the `Canvas` and set the `Canvas` size to be large enough to surround all of the elements.

Comment: That did it, I set ScrollViewer height to 500 and solved it. Thanks!